# Deleting a specific key from a file using file I/O in C++

Tags: c++, string, file-handling

```
string _delete_an_apiKey(int n) 
{
    string a;
    string del;
    int cnt = 0;
    ofstream f1("tempAPIKeys.dat",ios::app);    // Temporary file for executing deletion
    ifstream f2(file,ios::in);                  // Main file containing all the keys
    while(!f2.eof()) 
    {
        if(cnt != n) 
        {
            f2 >> a;
            f1 << a << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            f2 >> del;
        }
        ++cnt;
    }
    f1.close();
    f2.close();
    remove(fileName);
    rename("tempAPIKeys.dat",fileName);
    return del;
}
```

> n is basically like an index which is associated with each key

> in this case n = 0, meaning delete the first key

In this code, I have partially succeeded in deleting the key of my choice but it gives an unexpected output. Let me give you an example by giving the **contents of the file**:

Before the execution :

```
x4pDtc3vI8yHFDar99GUdkPh
0RxLFwFhcyazoZ0zBKmPFR4q
4Haw6HSUQKDhNSxeD0JKMcFT
```

After the execution :

```
0RxLFwFhcyazoZ0zBKmPFR4q
4Haw6HSUQKDhNSxeD0JKMcFT
4Haw6HSUQKDhNSxeD0JKMcFT
```

The function also returns the deleted string.

Now you can easily tell that I have deleted the first key but I don't know **why the last key is stored twice.**

Comment: As a side note, your usage of `while(!f2.eof())` looks [wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-i-e-while-stream-eof-cons) and you should check before readings are successful before using what are "read".

Comment: `_delete_an_apiKey` That name is reserved for the language implementation in the global namespace. If you define such function, the behaviour of the program will be undefined. You should use another name for the function.

Comment: @eerorika I am so sorry about the function naming, I will correct that once it starts running

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you see last key twice is because the `iostream::eof` is raised after reading the end of the stream, it does not mean that the next read will be end of file.

Use `inputStream >> data` in the while loop, which guarantee entering the loop if the read was successful, like:

```
while(f2 >> a) 
{
  if(cnt != n) 
  {
    f1 << a << endl;
  }
  else
  {
    del = a;
  }
  ++cnt;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your order of operations is wrong. What you do:

- check if read was EOF
- read from file
- use the result

As a consequence when when EOF is reached, you use the last result again.

The correct order:

- read from file
- check if read was EOF
- use the result only if result was not EOF

Furthermore, you don't check for cases where read fails for other reasons.

Comment: @VaibhavSharma For example, if the file doesn't exist then you attempt to read, which will fail. Then you output empty string as if you had read a file that was empty.

Comment: Is that the only condition that needs to be checked? Because I already checked this condition before entering the function

Comment: @VaibhavSharma What if the file is deleted in between? And no, it is not the only condition. There can be many reasons why reading a file fails.

Comment: Ok, understood, but I tried the above method but it failed

Comment: I mean your answer